# table layout - fixed column - android

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

i am able to implement the table layout with header (row) and the column1 as in the picture. But I wish to display Col1 constantly on the screen even when the table is scrolled horizontally. 
any work around?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create 2 different UI elements

Column 1 as ListView and rest as a TableLayout.

You need to capture the touch event on the UI Component and the pass it to the other so that scroll of both the component are in sync.
Thats my opinion, there can be a different solution to it as well.

Comment: @khotmanish..wouldn't this approach make the scroll sluggish? i have implemented this using two list views and the result was, a very sluggish scroll...

Comment: There is no specific reason for this to be sluggish. I had implemented it in the past and it worked fine for me. Using the listview also takes care or recycling the views and hence there would be less GC calls.

Comment: Ya but then it was for a client project so cant share it wit you... sorry for that :(